# javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to configure Spring in the way so that it will inject all the instances of EntityManager class in my project but I'm constantly getting the following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
```

Here are the related configurations in my spring-config.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="spring.homework"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="sql.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${dataSource.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${dataSource.url}"
        p:username="${dataSource.userName}"
        p:password="${dataSource.password}"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"/>
    </property>
</bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
            p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
```

Here are the contents of persistence.xml

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="default"  transaction-type="JTA">
        <!--<jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>-->
        <properties>
            <property name="connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And finally here are the dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

All the similar questions I've found have been resolved by upgrading to JPA 2.1 version but as you can see mine is 2.1. I've tried to clean and install maven a couple of times but that didn't helped. 
I'm really stuck and I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: provider tag is missing in persistence.xml file..<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>. It might be an issue..

Comment: Actually it's in spring-config.xml and in my case it's org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider

Comment: What server are you using to run your app ?

Comment: What i did mean is tomcat/jboss/jetty and which version ?

Comment: None of them it's just a simple console application

Comment: How do you run this app? From eclipse?

Comment: Intellij I've already solved the problem thank you very much Pawel

Comment: NoSuchMethodError with some JPA class is a dup of many many posts in this site. Nothing to do with database, or provider. You have the wrong version of JPA API

Comment: this same error get in WebLogic how to this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved the problem, there was an old version of javax.persistence.jar in my lib folder which I guess has been preventing maven dependency from loading. So after I manually deleted it everything started to work.
Thank you very much to all those who've been trying to help me.